# combine 2 select queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 select statements:

1. timestamp of emp getting awards for specific emp id

   `SELECT * FROM user_table,employeetable,awards  where user_table.empid=employeetable.empid AND user_table.empid=awards.empid  AND user_table.empid=123 ORDER BY timestamp DESC`
2. All employees staying around 25 miles from the current loc:`current location: lat =37 lng=-122`

   `SELECT * ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) )+ sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM user_table,employeetable,awards  where user_table.empid=employeetable.empid AND user_table.empid=awards.empid  HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;`

How do I combine both and ORDER BY timestamp ?btw both have field timestamp.

1.has specific user
2.all users within specific radius

I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two queries into a single query, just using logic in the `where` clause (which this has turned into a `having` clause:

```
select *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) )+ sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) as distance
from user u join
     employee e
     on u.empid = e.empid join
     awards a
     on u.empid = a.empid
having empid = 123 or distance < 25;
```

This uses `having` instead of `where` so the `distance` column alias can be used instead of the formula.

Comment: what if there are more empid. ie: instead of only 123 I have  123,234,567,789,102 .Then will the code above change to IN ?basically when i have group of empids.

Comment: Yes, you would have `empid in (123, 234, 567, 789, 102)` as the first condition.

Comment: so I need to replace empid=123 to `empid in (123, 234, 567, 789, 102)` with `HAVING` behind empid thats it?

Comment: Yes.  That is the way.

Comment: query:`SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT * FROM user u
   INNER JOIN employee e ON (u.empid = e.empid)
   INNER JOIN awards a ON (u.empid = a.empid)
   WHERE u.empid = 123

   UNION

   SELECT * ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) )+ sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
   FROM user u
   INNER JOIN employee e ON (u.empid = e.empid)
   INNER JOIN awards a ON (u.empid = a.empid)
   HAVING distance < 25
   ORDER BY distance
) a
ORDER BY timestamp DESC` error "`The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`

Comment: I had a query ,the code above which was suggested by another person gave this error ,i guess as distance column was extra in 2nd query.How do resolve the problem if situation like tat arrives ?Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I posted new q with the same doubt ,Sir please look into it .Thanks for your time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222653/select-statements-have-a-different-number-of-columns