# SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried using the code below and it says

> The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

because distance column in added is more in 2nd query .How do I resolve something like this or can I get the order right without distance column?I really appreciate any help.THanks in Advance.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT * FROM user u
   INNER JOIN employee e ON (u.empid = e.empid)
   INNER JOIN awards a ON (u.empid = a.empid)
   WHERE u.empid = 123

   UNION

   SELECT * ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) )+ sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
   FROM user u
   INNER JOIN employee e ON (u.empid = e.empid)
   INNER JOIN awards a ON (u.empid = a.empid)
   HAVING distance < 25
   ORDER BY distance
) a
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: The problem is that the second one has `distance` and the first doesn't, although I would expect the second one to just generate an error.  I didn't realize that the comma after `*` is optional.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it ,I tried executing the 2nd code and 1st code separately it works fine .btw I had to add `,` after `*`.But how can you have `UNION` for uneven columns like the above case other than the code which you suggested in previous question.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would fix this by adding distance to the first query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT *, NULL as distance FROM user u
   INNER JOIN employee e ON (u.empid = e.empid)
   INNER JOIN awards a ON (u.empid = a.empid)
   WHERE u.empid = 123

   UNION

   SELECT *,  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) )+ sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
   FROM user u
   INNER JOIN employee e ON (u.empid = e.empid)
   INNER JOIN awards a ON (u.empid = a.empid)
   HAVING distance < 25
   ORDER BY distance
) a
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: I get duplicate column name `sno` .Sorry.

Comment: @BarbC.Goldstein . . . That is a very strong accusation, especially since I made a comment explaining exactly what the problem was long before your post appeared.  It is not uncommon for two people to arrive at an answer and to post in close time proximity.

Comment: @BarbC.Goldstein Sorry Mr.BarbC ,I was in conversation with Mr.Gordon and he posted the code right after that .Thats why I accepted that.Thanks again.Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I still get this error : I get duplicate column name `SNO` how do I fix this ?

Comment: @jason . . . Because you don't actually want `select *`.  The same column name may be used in different tables.  You can say `select u.*,  ` and then list the individual columns from the other tables.

Comment: My apologies gentlemen. New here, trying to build my reputation, so over-reacted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added `u1.  *,` and `u2.  *,` above and below and works fine I tried adding even e1 and a1 like this `u1. ,a1. ,e1.  *,` but its giving me an error .How do I add even that in the select like `u1. *,` ?  Sorry for asking so many queries.

Comment: @jason . . . You need to add in the columns you want explicitly.  With the `*`, there is a naming conflict.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your 1st `SELECT` and 2nd `SELECT` have varying number of columns, since you introduced `Distance` in 2nd `SELECT`.

So try making `Distance` in 1st query null or 0 as follows.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT *, 0 as Distance
   FROM user u
   INNER JOIN employee e ON (u.empid = e.empid)
   INNER JOIN awards a ON (u.empid = a.empid)
   WHERE u.empid = 123

   UNION

   SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) )+ sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
   FROM user u
   INNER JOIN employee e ON (u.empid = e.empid)
   INNER JOIN awards a ON (u.empid = a.empid)
   HAVING distance < 25
   ORDER BY distance
) a
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```